# React and setState and autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, web-component, material-ui

Im using react and material ui.
This is my component

```

```
import React from 'react';


import lightBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/lightBaseTheme';

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';
// the light theme
const lightMuiTheme = getMuiTheme(lightBaseTheme);

// the autocomplete component width
const Preferencestypeahead = {
maxWidth: 600,
position:'relative',
margin:'auto'
}


export default class Preferences extends React.Component {


constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.handleUpdateInput = this.handleUpdateInput.bind();
this.state = {
  dataSource: [],
};
}

handleUpdateInput(value){
this.setState({
  dataSource: [
    value,
    value + value,
    value + value + value,
  ],
});
};

render() {
return (


    <div>
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={lightMuiTheme}> 

                    <section style={Preferencestypeahead}>
                            <AutoComplete
                              hintText="Type"
                              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                              onUpdateInput={this.handleUpdateInput.bind(this)}
                              floatingLabelText="Search"
                              fullWidth={true}
                            />                          
                    </section>

        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </div>

    )

   }
  }
```

I keep getting setState is not defined when I type anything inside the autocomplete. Where could I be going wrong? I have also faced this problem when I tried to import the tabs as well

Comment: should be `this.handleUpdateInput.bind(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to "`this`"

This line is the problem:

```
this.handleUpdateInput = this.handleUpdateInput.bind();
```

Change it to:

```
this.handleUpdateInput = this.handleUpdateInput.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using ES6 you could just do

```
...
onUpdateInput={(val) => this.handleUpdateInput(val)}
...
```

then you don't need to do this --> `this.handleUpdateInput = this.handleUpdateInput.bind(this);` in your constructor